# Decision to center fixed effects in GLMMs in lme4

Tags: r, centering, lme4-nlme

I'm constructing a GLMM using lme4 in R, and am unsure as to when it is and isn't best practice to center fixed effects.

For this model (with logit link), for example:

```
model <- glmer(dependent_variable ~ continuous_variable*categorical_variable + (1|random_variable), data = d, family = binomial)
```

should the categorical_variable first be centered as well as the continuous_variable? e.g. redefining to use

```
d$categorical_variable.ct <- d$categorical_variable - mean(d$categorical_variable)
```

I understand how centering can help convergence issues and reduce collinearity ([see here](https://hlplab.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/centering-several-variables/)), and how it affects the reading of the model intercept and fixed effects coefficients. Therefore as far as I know it always makes sense to first center continuous variables?s

I've had conflicting advice on whether or not to center categorical variables, however. [This website](https://hlplab.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/centering-several-variables/) seems to suggest you should, while I've also been advised not to, on the grounds that it doesn't make any sense to.

In the particular case I'm looking at here, my categorical variable is one of two experimental conditions. They are roughly balanced, so that after centering one is -0.501 and one is 0.499. But in the past I've also had datasets which have been unbalanced (i.e. with twice as much data in one condition over the other).

Crucially, the decision of whether to center a categorical variable or not influences the inferences I would draw from my data.

Comment: After you center the categorical variable, do you keep it as a numeric? Or convert it back to categorical?

Comment: nxy, what you are doing when you center is to change the contrasts, you have to google for contrasts, then you will find plenty of discussions on the topic. See e.g. Centering Categorical Predictors in Multilevel Models: Best Practices and Interpretation https://quantpsy.org/pubs/yaremych_preacher_hedeker_(in.press).pdf

Answer (score 0):

My reach on mixed modeling practice is very limited, but I recently came across such a discussion (relevant more to `lmer` family of mixed models, though) and thought you'd find it helpful.

Centering of continuous variables do have important implication, when you partition a variance to separate it's fixed and random effects, essentially done using of one or more switch variables. These switch variables turn certain effects on or off in the model when combined with design effects terms depending on their states (for e.g., 0 or 1). When you need to encode one of these state variables as numeric (for discussion about when one requires to do so, I refer to an article below), the impact of centering the variables becomes relevant. Once centered, the numerically encoded switch variable breaks, and computing it's effect does not make sense.

Other times, centering of variables might not make an impact  when you want to just test your hypothesis (in p-values and test statistic). It might affect the effect size estimate though (found somewhere exemplified in stack-exchange thread).

I suggest you take a look at [this](https://dl.sciencesocieties.org/publications/aj/abstracts/108/6/2256) article, in particular page 5. Here, the authors provide a case for the use of switch variables in variance partitioning with a caution about mean-centering the covariates.

Comment: Not sure if this answer addresses the question asked, which is about centering categorical variables.

Comment: Centering a categorical variable does imply that it is converted to a numeric scale first. But, as questioner speaks of group balance, unless they are convinced it is so, I can't make sense of what possible use it has.